# Equivalente a "Position relative" en XML android studio, superponer layouts

Tags: android, xml, layout

¿Como puedo superponer dos layout con el fin de crear el efecto de la imagen con el numero 2 mediante XML en android?

Creo haber leído en algún momento una propiedad que funciona parecido a lo que es en CSS position relative, que permitía mover los elementos desde su posición inicial

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si **fijas un tamaño para el linearlayout de encima** entonces pueden calcular el margen superior por medio de **medidas dp** para colocar el segundo linearlayout.

Necesitas contener tus 2 linearLayout en un RelativeLayout y jugar con los márgenes como ya te mencionó Erick Silva.

Al LinearLayout que quieres que se situé detrás y un poco abajo solo establece un Margin top con la mitad del tamaño del primer LinearLayout pero te repito, el primero debe tener tamaño fijo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="8dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="linear" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="linear" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para suporponer layouts como en la imagen 2 basta que esten contenidos en un RelativeLayout y luego jugar un poco con los margenes o la alineacion, mientras que si queres que un layout se muestre despues del otro como en la imagen 1 el contenedor debe ser un LinearLayout

Aca te dejo como yo haria el XML para que quede como en la segunda imagen:

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:layout_margin="20dp"
      android:background="#DD00AA">
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
      android:background="#0066ff"/>
   </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Te muestro la forma en que lo haría utilizando `CardView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--EL CardView te permitira establecer una elevacion para el primer contenedor del Titulo-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#b459ff"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="1dp">

        <!-- Contenedor 1 -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <!-- Titulo -->
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Linear"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <!-- Contenedor 2 -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#595cff">

        <!-- Titulo -->
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Linear"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Espero te sirva, saludos.